# What is the difference between a 21(1) and a 21(4) notice?

Tags: england-and-wales, tenancy-rules, assured-shorthold-tenancy

Why are these two distinct subsections and often distinguished in terms of references to the notices themselves? Is each subsection required to be used in different respective contexts?

(References are to s21, Housing Act 1988.)

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere: context, context, context. I know what you mean, because you've asked lots of questions about tenancies lately. Someone stumbling on this question in 6 months' time, who isn't well versed in the subject, will have absolutely _no_ clue what you're talking about. Please make your questions as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [section 21 of the Housing Act 1988](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/50/section/21), when using a section 21 notice to inform the tenant that the landlord would like to end an assured shorthold tenancy:

Section 21(1) applies when attempting to end a fixed term tenancy, while section 21(4) applies when attempting to end a periodic tenancy. The wording of these two subsections states this.